# How to add a line break with .setattribute()?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner programmer which have appended a list of buttons into a `div`. However, the list of buttons are side by side as shown below here,
[image]
I want a line break after each button so they will be on top of each other instead.
My codes to append using `.setattribute()` are as shown below,

```
<script>

        var arr = [{"userid": "jim", "title":"help"}, {"userid": "pim", "title":"hello"}]  

        var i;
        $("enquirieswall").empty();
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                          var a = document.createElement("button");
                          a.setAttribute("href", "#");
                          //a.textContent = arr[i].title;
                          a.innerHTML = arr[i].title.toString();
                          a.setAttribute("class", "btn");
                          a.setAttribute("type", "button");
                          a.setAttribute("onclick", "window.location='enquiriesdetails.php?enid=" + arr[i].enid + "&userid=" +arr[i].userid +"'");
                          $("#enquirieswall").append(a);
                        }
        </script>

        <div id="enquirieswall"></div>
```

Comment: Where is 'enid ' in you array?

Comment: Add this: $("#enquirieswall").append('<br>');

Comment: Why not using CSS instead? a `.btn{ display: block; }` will do. And why using `setAttribute` to set the className and the onclick event listener, you can use `.className = ` and `.onclick = ` instead.

Comment: Unrelated, but *never* do `a.setAttribute("onclick", ...)`. Attach an event listener [with vanilla JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) or [with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Or, in this case, just put the link in the href attribute – using JavaScript to make an <a> tag to open a link is just silly.

Comment: Guys, all these solutions were what I wanted so feel free to put them as answers if you want, and I like the css one more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I picked the CSS solution in the end. I also aligned the buttons and set a fixed width.

```
<style>
.btn{
    display: block; 
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
    width: 80%;
}
</style>
```

end result:
[image]